# Replace icons in a return() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Ok, so I have 5 stars (`<StarBorderIcon/>`) on some product from the website material-ui. I want to replace them with a filled star (`<StarIcon/>`) depending on how much rating is inserted into the function. I tried to use `replace()` but I saw that it only took strings. Is there a way to replace them in a simple way? I can't use if's or while loops in a return so I'm out of ideas on what to do.

Also what are these (`<StarIcon/>`) generally/usually called? I'm not sure if the icons in code from that website has a specific name.

Here is the code where the icons come from.

```
import StarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import StarBorderIcon from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';
```

Comment: Are you using react? Can you post the snippet of code that renders these icons right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, you always render a fresh copy of your component based on the data you have available. So you don't "replace" anything al all, you just render it the way you want.

That means you could do something like:

```
function Stars({ rating }) {
  return <div className="stars">
    { rating >= 1 ? <StarIcon/> : <StarBorderIcon/> }
    { rating >= 2 ? <StarIcon/> : <StarBorderIcon/> }
    { rating >= 3 ? <StarIcon/> : <StarBorderIcon/> }
    { rating >= 4 ? <StarIcon/> : <StarBorderIcon/> }
    { rating >= 5 ? <StarIcon/> : <StarBorderIcon/> }
  </div>
}
```

This react component will render five stars and check to see if each star has enough `rating` to be filled in. It takes more and more rating to fill in each star.

Which you would use like:

```
<Stars rating={4} />
```

---

> Also what are these (`<StarIcon/>`) generally/usually called?

That is a react component that is imported from Material UI. It can be treated and rendered like any other react component.

---

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mmbuad)

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to react and kinda new to Javascript and I should've made that clear. I understand most of the code but what does the "?" and the ":" do?

Comment: That is known as a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). If the part before the `?` is true, then it returns the part after the `?`. If it is not true, the part after the `:` is returned instead. So in plain english that says: "if the rating is 5 or less then return a filled in star, else return a hollow star"

Comment: Aha, thanks! I'll be sure to add them to my toolbox in the head!